# np.maximum for scalar and pandas Series without np.nan

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a list of `pd.Series` and scalar values (float and int) which I'd like to find the element-wise maximum for (Series are all same length). If there is a `np.nan` value, another value should be used (`np.nan` if only nans are available). This works fine as long as the series or values in the list don't contain nan values, but if they do the nans dominate the resulting series.

```
rv = input_list[0]
for s in input_list[1:]:
  rv = np.maximum(s, rv)
```

As an example

```
input_list = [pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 1]), 2, pd.Series([3, 1, np.nan, 4])]
```

should return:

```
pd.Series([3, 2, 3, 4])
```

How can I modify this code to take care of nan values and ignore them if there are alternative values?

Comment: Can you add some data sample?

Comment: Guessing you want `pd.Series.cummax`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution using `numpy.nanmax`

You are looking for [`numpy.nanmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nanmax.html). From its documentation:

> Return the maximum of an array or maximum along an axis, ignoring any
>   NaNs. When all-NaN slices are encountered a **RuntimeWarning is raised**
>   and NaN is returned for that slice.

So if you know that the maximum size of the series is `n`:

```
n= 4
result = pd.Series(np.nanmax(
    [np.full(n, i) if np.isscalar(i) else i for i in input_list], axis=0))
```

#### Running it on the example:

```
input_list = [pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 1]), 2, pd.Series([3, 1, np.nan, 4])]
result = pd.Series(np.nanmax(
    [np.full(n, i) if np.isscalar(i) else i for i in input_list], axis=0))
```

**Output:**

```
0    3.0
1    2.0
2    3.0
3    4.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: I need the element-wise result (one value per each item in the `Series`), i.e. a Series as result, not one scalar value. Essentially what `np.maximum` does, but with different nan-handling.

Comment: Ok, let me fix that.

Comment: Done, is this what you need?

Comment: `nanmax` returns the maximum of an array. I need the maximum across a number of arrays/series for each element (see the example which I had added).

Comment: It seems to do exactly what you have specified in your example, what am I missing?

Comment: Bad choice of example. It had the same result for your algorithm as was expected in the example (I changed it). Try `[pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 1]), 2, pd.Series([3, 1, np.nan, 4])]`. I'd expect a series of length 4, not 3 (your code) as result.

Comment: I am trying to understand how your code would proceed to generating the result you've given, would it be possible to extend the explanation of what exactly you would like the algorithm to do?

Comment: Just like what I describe. It's a utility function that should provide the element-wise maximum of various series/arrays or scalar values.

Comment: Ah, ok, so the second element `2` counts as a `[2,2,2,2]`?

Comment: Ah, ok! That's easy, just a sec. But what about series of different sizes, like `[1,2,3]` and `[1,2,3,4,5]`? Should they have a padding with nans?

Comment: Is the maximum length known how should it be detected in an online fashion?

Comment: all series have the same length

Comment: So they are either integers or series of size `n`?

Comment: Updated answer to reflect the latest explanations. Is it correct now? I would recommend you to update your question too, so that it may be clearer what you are asking for, especially the aspect of treating integers implicitly as lists of size `n`.

Comment: Thanks - works fine. Interestingly, `np.nanmax` can cope with lists as input and doesn't require an `array`.

Comment: Just for later reference, the above solution isn't ideal as it destroys the series index because it's using Numpy which doesn't care much about the Pandas Series index (the series-wise `np.maximum()` manages to preserve the index though).